# Doctrine2 incorrectly cascading oneToMany relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, one-to-many

I have 2 doctrine entities:
Commessa

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type = "bigint")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/* ... */

/*
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "AppBundle\Entity\Pipeline\pipeline", mappedBy = "commessa", cascade = {"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $pipelines;
```

and Pipeline

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type = "bigint")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/* ... */

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "AppBundle\Entity\Commessa\commessa", inversedBy = "pipelines")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "id_commessa", name = "id")
 */
private $commessa;
```

As you can see, both entities have an AUTO-INCREMENT, single field primary key called id, and a bidirectional association to the other; pipeline gets automatically persisted whenever i do so with commessa.
Furthermore, both entities only have a getter method for the id, and not a setter one.

Now, whenever i try to flush an object instance of the class Commessa including more than a single pipeline, the following error pops up:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO pipeline (descrizione, nome_logico, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["", "frontend", "9"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9' for key 'PRIMARY'

At no point in my code i set the pipeline's id, and dumping the Commessa object right before the flush (and after the persist) shows that it's populated correctly, and the pipelines have "null" as id, which i guess is correct.

Through the Symfony profiler, the following queries are reported:

```
"START_TRANSACTION"
INSERT INTO commessa (codice_commessa, data_creazione, data_scadenza, descrizione, id_anagrafica, id_cliente, id_stato, id_tipo_commesa) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Parameters: [ 1 => lyme, 2 => 2017-01-13 10:47:53, 3 => 2017-01-17 00:00:00, 4 => Fai Lyme, 5 => 1, 6 => 1, 7 => 1, 8 => 1 ] 

INSERT INTO pipeline (descrizione, nome_logico, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
Parameters: [1 => , 2 => frontend, 3 => 10] 

INSERT INTO pipeline (descrizione, nome_logico, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
Parameters: [1 => , 2 => backend, 3 => 10] 
"ROLLBACK"
```

I then stumbled upon [the doctrine limitations and known issues page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html), stating at point 28.1.3

> There are two bugs now that concern the use of cascade merge in combination with bi-directional associations.
> but the related ticket link is dead.

Could this be my problem?
If it is, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: I'm assuming these two objects are not in fact the same object, added twice? (Since all their properties are the same)

Comment: I'm sorry, i mistakenly copied twice the same query; the second field is different.  I edited the question.

Comment: * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "id_commessa", name = "id") is wrong. there is 2 times name field

Comment: @JasminMistry Thank you for your answer; turns our you were right

Comment: Please accept ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ORM\JoinColumn(name = "id_commessa", name = "id") is wrong. there is 2 times name field